# Resharper 6.0 code analysis and font configuration unavailable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, code-analysis

After I uninstalled Resharper 5.0 and installed the latest 6.0, code analysis stopped working on VS 2010 (on vs 2008 it still works).

During investigation I noticed that Fonts and Colors is also not showing Resharper's items.
I tried clearing the Registry value at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\FontAndColors\Cache and it didn't work.

I tried uninstalling 6.0, resetting VS's settings, reinstalling 6.0.

I tried then repairing the installation for 6.0.

I tried disabling stylecop plugin for resharper.

I tried clearing the cache for the solution I'm working.

I tried creating a new project to see if it was yet something else related to my project.

I tried looking at the VS startup log, resharper starts with no errors.

I tried uninstalling 6.0 and installing 5.0 again, 5.0 is still working with code analysis and has fonts and colors configuration.

New ideas are welcome.

Comment: This might be an even better place to post your question: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper/resharper_community?view=discussions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you run Visual Studio with the following command line: 'devenv /ReSharper.LogFile C:\resharper_log.txt /ReSharper.LogLevel Verbose'.
After that, please create a new Class Library solution, verify the issue and send me a corresponding 'resharper_log.txt' file to "support[at]jetbrains.com".

Thanks.

Alex Berezoutsky,
Support Engineer,
JetBrains Inc.
"Develop with pleasure!"